# Scraping blocked by the site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all indexes from nasdaq, but when I execute the script, it stops there until I hit `Ctrl+C`. Does anyone know how to get around this? (Or even another page where I can get the indexes)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as ur
url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/quotes/nasdaq-ndx-index"

read_data = ur.urlopen(url).read()
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(read_data,"lxml")

print(soup_data.prettify())
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I would suggest using requests library, it is simple and complete, just import as ```import requests``` and get text like: ```requests.get(url).text```

Comment: Hi! The problem is not in the code (I think), it works well with onther urls. It's nasdaq.com that blocks the scraping - I suppose.

Comment: What is it you wanna scrape from that site? The tabular content are dynamic and they are not present in the page source. However, you can find them within some script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a response, add the [`user-agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header. Here's an example using the `requests` module:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/quotes/nasdaq-ndx-index"

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS).content
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

print(soup_data.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have made an unusually large amount of requests directed toward the site and as a result have had your IP Address blacklisted, then I wouldn't say that a client-side block on scraping is the issue.

Instead, my experience with NASDAQ has shown me that it is a dynamically loaded site. Hence, a package like requests might not be the correct tool.

For simple requests such as yours, I would suggest using a package like Selenium (in headless mode). It's heavier than requests, and has a learning curve but offers far more dynamic solutions for many of your scraping needs.

Happy scraping.